# Android USB OTG error message: USB device not supported

Tags: android, usb-otg

Bought a USB OTG adapter for my HTC One, and attached a thermal printer to it.
The phone responds with this popup:

Title- "USB device not supported"

Message- "The USB device you have connected is not supported. Please unplug both the USB device and the dongle.

Why is this, if i can attach the printer to a PC and have it enumerate, why can't my phone do the same via OTG? is there any way i can get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably someone made the decision in UsbHostManager not to support this device or this class/subclass of USB device.  Most likely, device drivers are missing within HTC One for the printer.  Support at HTC should be able to answer this question.